# How to remove date header from apache?

Tags: apache, http, apache2, http-headers

I need to minimize Apache HTTP response headers, by now i reduced them as following

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Mar 2010 21:57:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to disable Date and Server header, only for a certain virtual host.

Thank you!

Comment: Even Google respond with that header. Please don't remove it. A few bytes of bandwidth saved per request is the lowest priority in optimization.

Comment: i totally agree with you, but i'm asking because i need this not for a web site but for a web service

Comment: I can not remove date header from golang net/http server too.

Answer (score 6):

The Date header is required at part of the HTTP standard. You can't remove it without being non-compliant with the http standard, so apache doesn't generally allow that.

Comment: Are you sure it's part of the HTTP standard? Where's the supporting article?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.18 - `RFC 2616, section 14.18` "Origin servers MUST include a Date header field in all responses, except in these cases..."

Comment: @dannysauer This comment is factually correct, but misleading, because the following *"except in these cases"* paragraph includes "If the server does not have a clock that can provide a reasonable approximation of the current time". So server admins are allowed to omit the Date header at their leisure as long as they feel, that it "can not provide a reasonable approximation of the current time".

Comment: No, it's not misleading at all. In the context of the question asked, one virtual host on the same server is exceptionally unlikely to be unable to provide a reasonable approximation of the current time. This isn't a court of law; it's the internet - where things work together because most people work in good faith to follow the intent of the RFCs. Reading the rest of that exception, it's plain to see that the authors were referring to servers *without a clock*. That's why 14.18.1 is titled "clockless servers". :)

Comment: Can we change the timezone instead of GMT ?

Comment: No, you have to use GMT-

All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time
   (GMT), without exception. For the purposes of HTTP, GMT is exactly
   equal to UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). This is indicated in the
   first two formats by the inclusion of "GMT" as the three-letter
   abbreviation for time zone, and MUST be assumed when reading the
   asctime format. HTTP-date is case sensitive and MUST NOT include
   additional LWS beyond that specifically included as SP in the
   grammar.