# HTTP headers automatically set

Tags: apache, http

I am starting to learn about http correctly.

I am working in lamp stack.

On the command line i am requesting a local page which will be served with apache to see the headers that are returned.

```
curl -i local.testsite
```

The page i am requesting has no content and i am not setting any headers but there are already a lot of headers sent in the response such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2013 20:28:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

So if i am not setting these, does apache set these automatically?

Comment: short answer... yes.

Comment: Yes, apache sets them automatically. You can set that `Server:` and `X-Powered-By:` are not by default.

Answer (score 3):

Some are set by PHP:

- The `X-Powered-By` header is set by the `expose_php` INI setting.
- The `Content-Type` header is set by the `default_mimetype` INI setting.

The others are set by Apache:

- The `Server` header is set by the `ServerSignature` directive.
- The `Vary: Accept-Encoding` header is usually sent when `mod_deflate` is enabled.

`Date` and `Content-Length` are not configurable as they are part of the HTTP spec. `Date` is [included as a MUST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.18) (except under some conditions) and `Content-Length` [as a SHOULD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.13).

See also [How to remove date header from apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519743/how-to-remove-date-header-from-apache) and [How to disable the Content-Length response header with Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847238/how-to-disable-the-content-length-response-header-with-apache).

Answer (score 3):

Yes Apache is setting those by default.  By the way, if you only care about the headers, you should use

```
curl -I local.testsite
```

`-I` returns the headers only (HTTP HEAD request), such that even if you had content on the page you would only get the header.